# Greedy and non-greedy regex

Tags: regex

I currently have this regex: `this\.(.*)?\s[=,]\s`, however I have come across a pickle I cannot fix.

I tried the following Regex, which works, but it captures the space as well which I don't want: `this\.(.*)?(?<=\s)=|(?<!\s),`. What I'm trying to do is match identifier names. An example of what I want and the result is this:

`this.""W = blah;` which would match `""W`. The  second regex above does this almost perfectly, however it also captures the space before the `=` in the first group. Can someone point me in the correct direction to fix this?

EDIT: The reason for not simply using `[^\s]` in the wildcard group is that sometimes I can get lines like this: `this. "$ = blah;`

EDIT2: Now I have another issue. Its not matching lines like `param1.readBytes(this.=!3,0,param1.readInt());` properly. Instead of matching `=!3` its matching `=!3,0`. Is there a way to fix this? Again, I cannot simply use a `[^,]` because there could be a name like `param1.readBytes(this.,3$,0,param1.readInt());` which should match `,3$`.

Comment: in what language are you writting your program?

Comment: so how can you tell if a comma belongs to a this.identifier or as a seperator for the function arguments?

Comment: Is there a way to read backwards in Regex? For example, start at the `;` and work back until you have passed two `,` then start capturing until you find `this.`? Or is that not possible...

Comment: well in that case what happens if the 3rd parameter has a `this.,3$` in it?

Comment: it won't, and if it does, then I would want to extract it so the regex would still be valid. I think I can solve Edit2 with anchoring to the end of the line and then doing something like `this\.(.*)?,.*?,.*);$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(.*)` will match any character including whitespace.
To force it not to end in whitespace change it to `(.*[^\s])`

Eg:
`this\.(.*[^\s])?\s?[=,]\s`

For your second edit, it seems like you are doing a language parser. Even though regular expressions are powerful, they do have limits. You need a grammar parser for that.

Comment: then try this `this\.(.*[^\s])?\s?[=,]\s`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can tell in your first block to capture non space characters, instead of any.

```
this\.(\S*)?(?<=\s)=|(?<!\s),
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question, the field name can contain spaces in to so that's a no go.